# LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin' when using django-configurations

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to Django and I'm trying to set up a new project, using django-configurations to manage the config of Development, Staging and Production environments.
https://pypi.org/project/django-configurations/

I followed the quickstart guide, but after setting things up I keep getting this error when running `manage.py runserver`:

```
File "[path_redacted]/django_test/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 165, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.
```

This is a brand new blank project, no apps and no changes whatsoever from the default project setup. I only set up django-configurations as per the quickstart guide.

I have `manage.py` set up as per the guide:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_test.settings')
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_CONFIGURATION', 'Development')
    try:
        from configurations.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then do the same with `settings.py`, by adding the below class just after the default definition of `BASE_DIR`:

```
class Development(Configuration):
    DEBUG = True
```

The default installed apps are there and untouched, including the admin app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

If I comment out the default admin path in `urls.py` then `manage.py runserver` works fine, but then of course I have no access to the admin page.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here, but I just can't figure out what.

Comment: Did you try running `python -m manage runserver --settings=mysite.settings --configuration=Development`?  Of course, change `mysite` to the name of your project.  Have you also changed your **wsgi.py** file, adding `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_CONFIGURATION', 'Development')`?

Comment: @raphael Yes, I tried all of that, same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone runs into the same issue, I figured out the solution.
Based on the django-configurations quickstart guide it sounded like you have to define your Configuration class with constants that you want to differ in your various environments, like so:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
class Development(Configuration):
    DEBUG = True
```

However, that will not work. Everything that's in the settings.py file has to be set up for each of your enviromnents. For example:

```
class Development(Configuration):
    BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]
    DEBUG = TRUE
```

So `django-configurations` ignores settings outside the Configuration classes, therefore the `admin` application wasn't in `INSTALLED_APPS`, hence the error.
I hope this answer helps someone out in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Admin will be available after creation of super user in django

Comment: Although I didn't have a superuser before, creating it makes no difference. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you create any app after creation of project.

Comment: Originally yes, but after running into this error I created a fresh project with absolutely no changes other than setting up django-configurations. So with or without any installed apps, the error is the same.